KendoDialog actions TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function
I want a Kendo Dialog with two bottons. The code in jsp file is below. Getting error when deleteRow fuction is called. I think it is because of actions block of code. It works when I remove actions.
    function deleteRow(rowdata) {
     $("#dialog").kendoDialog({
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px",
            title: "Delete row?",
            closable: true,
            modal: true,
            content: "<p>Are you sure you want to delete this row?<p>",
            actions: [
                { text: 'Cancel', action: onCancel },
                { text: 'Delete', primary: true, action: onDelete }
            ]
        });
    
     function onDelete(e) {
            // Delete action confirmed
            if(rowdata){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mvc/abc/service/" + finalRowval.id + "/xyz",
                    dataType: 'text/html',
                    data: "",
                    async: true,
                    success: function(response) {
                        //Handle success response
                        },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        // Handle error response
                        }
                });
            }

        }
}

But i am getting 'TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function' error on chrome console. When i remove actions part its working fine. Thanks.

When do you see that error? When the dialog shows or when you click Cancel or Delete?

Need more info because I can't recreate the error with the code shown. Is it in the onCancel or the onDelete? If the onDelete, where exactly? Before the ajax call or in the success or error handler? Does the request reach the server? Use the debugger or add console.log() statements to find where it fails. Clicking the error in the console may also give a clue.

@NigelK i have updated the question. The error is at function deleteRow(rowdata) {  I think it is because of actions block of code. It works when I remove actions.
